# Using Active Directory Service with FireDac

Tags: ado, ads, firedac

I am converting a project using ADO to connect to SQL Server to one that uses FireDac. With standard database connection I have successfully converted the ADO connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=my-sql-01
```

To the FireDac one:

```
OSAuthent=Yes;DriverID=MSSQL;Address=my-sql-01;Database=MyDatabase
```

However, it also uses Active Directory Service with the following ADO connection string:

```
Provider=ADsDSOObject;Encrypt Password=False;Mode=Read;Bind Flags=0
```

Can anyone help with converting this to the FireDac connection string please?